# Need help understanding a "distributive conditional types" example from the docs

Tags: typescript

Here's a link to the [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#example-1)

Here's a link to the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQg9gDwgEwGoEMA2BXCAeAFQD4oBeKAbygDctcAuKAqAXwG4AoUSWRFAQQBOg9CEIlyVdMNGMCAbQC6rTt2jwkycWSZQICYBAB2yAM5R0RkEqgB%20XpqEixCo9gC2AIwiDFJRhooGDj4xJxc4NAEAIw6gVqmwIIAlkYA5kSqkUwATHF8Wm5ePkqZETwEAMz5mniJKelQAD5QRd6CpWxAA)

Here's the code:

```
type BoxedValue<T> = { value: T };
type BoxedArray<T> = { array: T[] };
type Boxed<T> = T extends any[] ? BoxedArray<T[number]> : BoxedValue<T>;

type T1 = Boxed<string>;
type T2 = Boxed<number[]>;
type T3 = Boxed<string | number[]>;
```

**My questions are:**

1. How does `T extends any[]` work?
2. What does the `number` mean in `BoxedArray<T[number]>`?

Comment: 1. What do you mean how does it *work*? It means any T that's an array type. 2. It just means a number, an index. If T is an array type, T[number] is the type of the things *in* the array (the *"element type of the array"* per the docs you linked).

Comment: Thank you, sir! If `T[number]` is the type of the things in the array, then why I can create a type `type T4 = Boxed<string[]>` and the checker will allow it?

Comment: Why did you think it would not allow it? It's very similar to T2, which is one of the examples.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, because I saw `number` in the type and it confused me. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Well how does it work? It's just what stands there: it checks if T is (or is extended) an array => evaluates as true if T is an array
2. That's a "generic index" (It has a different name but I can't remember that one any more), I think an example makes it pretty clear:

   ```
   const list = [1, 2, 3] as const;
   type a = typeof list[number]; //evaluates to 1 | 2 | 3

   type l = any[];
   type m = l[number]; //evaluates to any
   ```

Comment: Thank you, sir! It's starting to make sense now! You're the best!

Comment: No problem, that's what the site is for :)